# Implementing page tilt and zoom on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html, css-transitions

I was trying to search a few messages in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) when I saw this:

[image: Stackoverflow Chat]

With the movement of mouse to left or right, the contents were tilting to left or right and with movement of mouse up and down, contents were zooming in or out. This was a really awesome effect and I really like it. I want to implement the same.

I checked the same page right now, and I can't see this.

Can somebody tell me how can I do this?

Comment: CSS transformations? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transforms

Comment: Something on your side. Did you happen to click the middle mouse button for example?

Comment: @TheBronx might be something like that, but it was automatically happening with movement over my mousepad :(

Comment: no, I even refreshed the page with a doubt that I might have control button or some other button pressed on my laptop, but this effect remained there

Comment: "animate" function from jquery can do this for us. If specify exact effects, I can give it a try - Cheers!!!

Comment: you can use javascript to capture mouse position and modify CSS transformation parameters accordingly

Comment: can someone please a fiddle example for this effect please?

Answer (score 1):

This would kind of rotate the screen to the direction of The mousepointer.

Here is an Example on [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/full/aJzsE)

All you need is to add an EventListener to the `body` for the `mousemove` event and apply a css3 Transformation.

As I never did this before, you may need to adjust the transformation a bit.

I used the `webkitTransform` property for example purposes. You may need to look for a compatibility list

[image]

Here is the code that did the transformation in the Image

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) {

  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var clientHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  var skew = {}
  skew.y = (20 * ((e.x / width) - 0.5)) 
  skew.x = -(20 * ((e.y / height) - 0.5));

  document.body.style.webkitTransform = "perspective("+clientHeight+"px) rotateX("+skew.x+"deg) rotateY("+skew.y+"deg)"
})
```

*Edit: used the bodys clientHeight as the perspective, seems a bit better*

Answer (score 0):

Well, its ugly but you can modify the transformation to make it look more realistic:
http://jsfiddle.net/c5E6g/

```
<div id="container">
    Hey!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    background-color:gray;
    border:1px solid #111;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "skewx("+e.clientX+"deg) translatex(150px)";
};
```

It's just a function that changes the transform skewX value. I've just used raw X cursor position, you can use the page width to calculate a more appropiate value. Or even better, modify skewY a little bit too.